# Python/Django global name 'x' is not defined

Tags: python, django, model, django-views

I don't know why but I'm calling a method from another view but now It doesn't work since I modified a try/except on my view. The except is used in all my views and it works perfecty.

This view should modify elements of a menu via a pre-filled form. Actually I can't access to this form with the error :

**Python/Django global name 'logoutUser' is not defined**

**Here is the view**

```
from views import B2BpartnerUser
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import MenuForm, MenuDetailForm
from .models import Menu, MenuParagraph, MenuItem, MenuItemProd
from django.db.models import Count
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


@login_required
def B2BpartnerMenuDetailModify(request, partnerId, menuId, menuItemId):
message = ''
e = B2BpartnerUser(request, partnerId)
try:
    menuDetail = Menu.objects.get(id=menuId)
    menuItem = MenuItem.objects.get(id=menuItemId)
    menuItemProd = MenuItemProd.objects.get(id=menuItemId)
except (Menu.DoesNotExist, MenuItem.DoesNotExist, MenuItemProd.DoesNotExist):
    return logoutUser(request)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MenuDetailForm(request.POST, mySelf=partnerId)
    if form.is_valid():
        descrShort = form.cleaned_data['descrShort']
        paragraph = form.cleaned_data['paragraph']
        producteur = form.cleaned_data['producteur']
        position = MenuItem.objects.filter(menuId = menuDetail).filter(paragraph = paragraph).count() + 1
        menuItem = MenuItem(menuId = menuDetail)
        menuItem.descrShort = descrShort
        menuItem.paragraph = paragraph
        menuItem.position = position
        menuItem.save()
        if producteur > 0:
            menuItemProd = MenuItemProd(menuItemId = menuItem)
            menuItemProd.entrepriseId = producteur
            menuItemProd.save()
        message = _('Details modified successfuly')
else:
    data = {'descrShort': menuItem.descrShort, 'paragraph': menuItem.paragraph, 'producteur': menuItemProd.entrepriseId}
    form = MenuDetailForm(mySelf=partnerId)
menuItems = MenuItem.objects.filter(menuId = menuDetail).select_related()
menus = Menu.objects.filter(entrepriseId=e)
menuParagraph = MenuParagraph.objects.filter(actif=1)
modifierDetail = True
detail = True
return render (request, 'front/B2Bmenu.html', {'MenuDetailForm': form, 'menus': menus, 'message': message, 'partnerId': partnerId, 'modifierDetail': modifierDetail, 'detail': detail, 'menuDetail': menuDetail, 'menuParagraph': menuParagraph, 'menuId': menuId, 'menuItems': menuItems})
```

**Here is the model**

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    validDate = models.DateTimeField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    entrepriseId = models.ForeignKey('Entreprise', null=True)
    midi = models.BooleanField()
    soir = models.BooleanField()
    prix = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=2, default=0)

class MenuItem(models.Model):
    menuId = models.ForeignKey('Menu', null=True)
    position = models.IntegerField()
    paragraph = models.ForeignKey('MenuParagraph', null=True)
    descrShort = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    descrLong = models.TextField()
class Meta:
    ordering = ['position']

class MenuItemProd(models.Model):
    menuItemId = models.ForeignKey('MenuItem', null=True)
    entrepriseId = models.ForeignKey('Entreprise', null=True)

class MenuParagraph(models.Model):
    actif = models.BooleanField()
    text = models.TextField()
    position = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['position']
```

If you need anything, I can give you more details and thank you if you have a proposition. Thank you for taking time on my topic :)

Comment: You need to import the view `logoutUser` before you can call it.

Comment: I don't understand why you've posted your model. More interesting would be where you think `logoutUser` is actually defined; is it another function in that views.py file? Is it imported into that file?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I posted my model in order to understand the objects of my view. If it's not necessary, I can delete it.

Comment: `logoutUser()` is only called if an exception occurs. Have you tried printing which exception is being raised, and which line is causing it? It probably worked before because no exception was being raised so execution passed to the code following the `except` handler, i.e. `logoutUser()` was not previously called.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid The import was done, I used other methods in the same view. I know the problem is on the try / except.

Comment: Really, it is not. There is nothing in that try/except that would cause logoutUser not to be found. Perhaps you should show the part of the view that defines or imports that function.

Comment: @Arkhall: so, where are you importing `logoutUser`. I don't see it in the imports that you've just added. Is a locally defined function?

Comment: @mhawke Ok the problem was there, but now I am really logout hahahahaha. Now I need to find why it log me out xP Thank you, maybe I'll write another topic but I need to code myself before.

Comment: @Arkhall: looking at the exceptions that you are handling, it will likely be because there is no entry in the `Menu` table for `menuId`, or no entry in `MenuItem/MenuItemProd` with an `id` of `menuItemId`. I'd suggest that the last one should be: `menuItemProd = MenuItemProd.objects.get(menuItemId=menuItemId)` as this is a foreign keys to `MenuItem.id`.

Comment: @mhawke Sorry, but It doesn't work as I expected. Actually I'm trying to not logout xD I'm trying to be in the try with your proposition, I know it's a little mistake, but I have to find it ^^ Thank you for the feedback :)

Comment: @Arkhall "Now I need to find why it log me out" : well plain simply too : because you asked for it in your except clause xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain simply: `logoutUser` isn't defined nor imported anywhere in your view. Remember Python has no real "global" namespace.